# Which property of polar has been applied to this proof.

Tags: geometry, proof-explanation, projective-geometry, inversive-geometry

[image: brokards theorem proof]

Which property of polar has been used please give its proof also.

Comment: fwiw, OP is referencing https://www.imomath.com/index.php?options=334&lmm=0 in an IMO prep site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [IMO training PDF](https://alexanderrem.weebly.com/uploads/7/2/5/6/72566533/projectivegeometry.pdf) does a better job of setting up poles, polars and Brokard's theorem.  Specifically, Lemma 4 seems to be what you want.